# docker ubuntu cron in CoreOS not run, funny behavior

Tags: ubuntu, docker, cron, coreos

I have a docker, which is based on ubuntu image.

https://github.com/kkpoon/docker-cron-example/tree/1733eef9b76d51fda038510f49eebd58d4528c54

It runs cron and works well in the docker hosted in ubuntu.

When I deploy it to a CoreOS host, it has funny behavior.

1. `docker run --rm --name example1 docker-cron-example`, 
   checked the cron is running as it appear in `docker exec example1 ps aux`
2. suppose the example cron echo to `/var/log/cron.log` for every minutes, however, nothing happen for every minutes
3. after some try, when I run `docker exec example1 crontab /crontab` to reinstall the crontab, or I goes into it `docker exec -it example1 /bin/bash` and perform `crontab -e`, no change to the content and `:w` to save it. **The cronjob could run!!!!**

What's wrong with the cron?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer

and the fix is to TOUCH the crontab file

https://github.com/kkpoon/docker-cron-example/commit/6f9938d6a742cf09a33881f07d62eebe22ae71c3#diff-cf427fa2c0d7ad197f95ae145b56db52R4

thanks this link: https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/issues/198